# How to access entity variable in controller function?

Tags: symfony, controller

I have a variable `private $groupId;` in entity. And there is a controller function `public function settingsListAction(Request $request)`

I want to access that `groupId` in controller function. How it can be achieved?

**Edit**

Controller function is

```
/**
 * Get all settings content list
 * @Route("settings", name="settings_list")
 */
public function settingsListAction(Request $request)
{
    // Cannot edit at all.
    //Fetch Current Financial Year target data to display that on "Road to paradise tab"
    $entity = new J1Setting();
    //do smthing 
    $groupIdValue = $entity->getGroup();

    $settingsGroup = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:J1SettingGroup')->findAll();

    $settingsList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:J1Setting')->findBy(array('groupId' => groupIdValue));

    return $this->render('default/settingsList.html.twig', array('settingsGroup' => $settingsGroup, 'settingsList' => $settingsList));
}
```

And entity is:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Component\Annotation\J1Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
* J1Setting
*
* @ORM\Table(name="j1_settings", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_SName", columns={"name"})})
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\J1SettingRepository")
* @J1Entity(auditClass="AppBundle\Component\Audit\J1AuditSetting")
*/
class J1Setting
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="setting_id", type="integer")
 * 
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $settingid;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="string", length=250, nullable=true)
 */
private $value;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="group_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $groupId;

/**
 * @var J1SettingGroup
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="J1SettingGroup", inversedBy="settings")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
*/
private $group;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="setting_type", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $settingType;



/**
 * Get settingid
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getSettingId()
{
    return $this->settingid;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return J1Setting
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set value
 *
 * @param string $value
 * @return J1Setting
 */
public function setValue($value)
{
    $this->value = serialize($value);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get value
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getValue()
{
    return unserialize($this->value);
}

/**
 * Return name replacing underscores with spaces
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getFriendlyName(){
    return str_replace('_', ' ', $this->getName());
}
/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 * @return J1Setting
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set groupId
 *
 * @param integer $groupId
 * @return J1Setting
 */
public function setGroupId($groupId)
{
    $this->groupId = $groupId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get groupId
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getGroupId()
{
    return $this->groupId;
}

/**
 * Set settingType
 *
 * @param string $settingType
 * @return J1Setting
 */
public function setSettingType($settingType)
{
    $this->settingType = $settingType;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get settingType
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSettingType()
{
    return $this->settingType;
}


/**
* Set group
*
* @param $group
* @return J1Setting
*/
public function setGroup($group = null)
{
$this->group = $group;

return $this;
}

/**
* Get group
*
* @return integer
*/
public function getGroup()
{
return $this->group;
}
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information! Where is this `$groupId` variable? Is it part of the controller class? Please provide a full example of your problem.

Comment: @EmanuelOster I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a getter in your entity

```
public function getGroupId(){
   return $this->groupId;
}
public function setGroupId($groupId){
   $this->groupId = $groupId;
}
```

and in your controller:

```
$entity = new J1Setting();
$entity->setGroupId(123);
$groupIdValue = $entity->getGroupId();
var_dump($goupIdValue) //outputs 123
```

Comment: Thanks but it is returning null.

Comment: I updated my answer, it's returning null if your entity has no groupId set.

Answer (score 0):

When using Doctrine, you shouldn't put foreign keys into an entity.
This means, `groupId` should not be part of your `J1Setting` entity. If you want to access the id of the associated group, then you have to use `$entity->getGroup()->getId()`. Obviously, this only works, if the entity actually **has** a group!

Comment: When using `$entity->getGroup->getId()` it gives error: Error: Call to a member function getId() on null

Comment: As I just explained, this only works if `$entity` has a group. Obviously this is not the case here. If you never set the group for the entity, it naturally will always be `null`

Comment: Can you please tell me what should I do now to get the value?

Comment: It works correct when I put static id by `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:J1Setting')->findBy(array('groupId' => '1'));`